# datatype/md5sum error with p2os_teleop

Tags: ros, ps3joy, teleop, md5, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

After successfully pairing the ps3-controller with bluetooth ($ rosrun ps3joy sixpair) and running ps3joy.py ($ rosrun ps3joy ps3joy.py) it shows "Connection activated" as expected.

But when I start teleop_joy.launch ($ roslaunch p2os_launch teleop_joy.launch) it shows:

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[p2os_teleop-1]: started with pid [23530]
process[pioneer_joy_controller-2]: started with pid [23532]
[ERROR] [1317809297.619312697]: Client [/p2os_teleop] wants topic /joy to have datatype/md5sum
[joy/Joy/e3ef016fcdf22397038b36036c66f7c8], but our version has [sensor_msgs/Joy/5a9ea5f83505693b71e785041e67a8bb].
Dropping connection.
```

I have used the ps3-controller with bluetooth before on a different pc and never had such a problem.
I've tried using an USB-bluetooth dongle instead of the built-in bluetooth but it didn't change anything.

Has anyone an idea what might be wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Greets, Andrew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11417/datatype/md5sum-error-with-p2os_teleop/) by [anbaldinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/1167/anbaldinger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is not on a hardware level. The joystick node is publishing on the topic /joy with message type sensor_msgs/Joy, whereas p2os_teleop is subscribing to /joy with message type joy/Joy.

Have you considered using the joy_node from package joy?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just figured this out with joystick_remapper. The problem is joy/Joy msg type is deprecated and you should use sensor_msgs/Joy instead. However, (in my case) joystick_remapper still subscribes to the old joy/Joy type. I made the change in joystick_remapper.py line 43:

```
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
```

Then in manifest.xml in the joystick_remapper package, remove

```
<depend package="joy"/>
```

and add

```
<depend package="sensor_msgs"/>
```

Do rosmake the package. Then you're good to run the joy_remap node.

---

Originally posted by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) with karma: 184 on 2012-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is how you get `p2os_teleop` to work in ROS Electric:

- In file `p2os/p2os_teleop/manifest.xml`:
- **Line 12**: `<depend package="joy"/>` ⇒
  `<depend package="sensor_msgs"/>`
- In file `p2os/p2os_teleop/src/p2os_teleop.cc`:
- **Line 54**: `#include "joy/Joy.h"` ⇒ `#include "sensor_msgs/Joy.h"`
- **Line 145**: `void joy_cb(const joy::Joy::ConstPtr& joy_msg)` ⇒ `void joy_cb(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy_msg)`
- To be able to recompile `p2os_teleop`, remove the file `ROS_NO_BUILD` from the folder `p2os/p2os_teleop`
- Once you have done that, run rosmake as sudo:
- `sudo -s`
- `rosmake p2os_teleop`

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-06-08**:
Note that if you are using the launch file in p2os_launch (teleop_joy.launch), you need to edit that too